# Different CSS on WIcket's FeedbackPanel

Tags: wicket, feedbackpanel

I have a Wicket application.
In the application the user can fill several fields in several forms.

I have a special place at the bottom where the user gets feedback (using a FeedbackPanel).
The feedback consists of success & error messages alike.

The thing is that I want to have different CSS styles for the different messages.

I already have the CSS styles I want to implement.
I can implement them successfully in the HTML form, but I get the same CSS style to both messages.

I want to have on the same feedback components different CSS styles according to the different severity of the message, so if the message is an "Error" - I want it to have a specific style, if it is "Success" I want it to have different style.

How can I point the FeedbackPanel to the specific CSS styles according to the severity of the message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a class which inherit FeedbackPanel and override getCSSClass method

```
public class CustomFeedbackPanel extends FeedbackPanel {

    public CustomFeedbackPanel(String id) {
        super(id);
    }

    public CustomFeedbackPanel(String id, IFeedbackMessageFilter filter) {
        super(id, filter);
    }

    @Override
    protected String getCSSClass(FeedbackMessage message) {
        String css;
        switch (message.getLevel()){
            case FeedbackMessage.SUCCESS:
                css = "alert success";
                break;
            case FeedbackMessage.INFO:
                css = "alert info";
                break;
            case FeedbackMessage.ERROR:
                css = "alert error";
                break;
            default:
                css = "alert";
        }

        return css;
    }
}
```